# Raspberry pi as vr headset

Tags: streaming-video

I have come to the conclusion that I want a VR headset for my PC. With the Blu-ray drive I can watch 3D Blu-ray and steam sports VR interface.  That said I don't want to shell out the cash for a VR headset so that leaves me building one.  I found a headset that uses a 4.5 to 6 inch phone and several small screens on eBay.  Thus brings us to the Raspberry Pi itself. My vision is to use the Pi as a second monitor to run the screen and audio as well as being a control interface with an accelerometer and some hand controls and then conections it to the PC using Bluetooth.  I have never used a Raspberry Pi so I have no clue if this is even possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a recent iPhone or Android phone, then the easiest and cheapest way to get into VR is one of the many [Google Cardboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cardboard) headsets. Cardboard headsets made from actual cardboard range from free to a few dollars, nice plastic headsets can be found from $15-$20. There are more expensive Cardboard compatible headsets, but they can be expensive.

The Pi3 is probably roughly comparable to late '90s SGI workstations like the [O2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SGI_O2), so you may be able to drive a pair of low-resolution screens with simple wireframe or non-textured triangles. But the amount of work necessary in terms of both hardware design and software development is likely to be substantial.

Further, the Pi doesn't have a video input port, so you are unlikely to be able to take video content from a PC and display it on a Pi. If you have the EE skills to DIY your own Rift headset, you are probably better off applying for a job at Oculus.

That said, the Pi can be an effective local [Cyberspace Deck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprawl_trilogy#Glossary), hosting a small web server that provides little VR apps written in Three.js or similar. You will still need separate hardware for your headset, but the Pi can be a great way to ensure that your demo content is always available, even when a network connection isn't.

Comment: thanks like I said I am not realy familiar with the Raspberry Pi platform but it sounds like it might be better off just wireing a hdmi from my graphics card to the monitor in the headset and using a aduino as a head tracking sensor

Comment: An AVR may be a much better choice for bringing sensor data into a VR headset. Linux is far from a real-time OS, so the Pi platform may introduce unwanted latency into your project. Additionally, after you prototype your project with Arduino, you can build your own minimal AVR board to keep volume and mass down. Critical considerations in VR.